# Getting only Response [200] from posting Trading API call request to Ebay

Tags: python, json, xml, python-requests, ebay-api

I can post Trading API AddItem call through using Python SDK (using JSON code) or through the API explorer on https://developer.ebay.com/ (using the same XML codes from the same XML file I used with the Python requests library below) and gets some response as usual.

However, when I tried to do so by calling through Python requests library with an xml file, I got no response and instead got <Response [200]>. Could someone pls take a look at my code below and see how I can fix it and get the normal response from Ebay?

Code:

```
import requests

# Set the name of the XML file.
xml_file = XML_FILE

headers = {'Content-Type':'text/xml', "X-EBAY-API-SITEID": "0",
"X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL": "967",
"X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME":"AddItem"}

# Open the XML file.
with open(xml_file) as xml:
    r = requests.post('https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll', data=xml, headers=headers)

print(r)
```

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AddItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken>TOKEN</eBayAuthToken>
  </RequesterCredentials>
   <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
   <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
  <Item>
      <Title>Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone</Title>
      <Description>
        This is the first book in the Harry Potter series. In excellent condition!
      </Description>
      <PrimaryCategory>
        <CategoryID>29223</CategoryID>
      </PrimaryCategory>
      <StartPrice>1.0</StartPrice>
      <CategoryMappingAllowed>true</CategoryMappingAllowed>
      <Country>US</Country>
      <Currency>USD</Currency>
      <PaymentMethods>CreditCard</PaymentMethods>
      <DispatchTimeMax>3</DispatchTimeMax>
      <ListingDuration>Days_7</ListingDuration>
      <ListingType>Chinese</ListingType>
      <PictureDetails>
        <PictureURL>https://mysamplepicture.com/14.jpg</PictureURL>
      </PictureDetails>
      <PostalCode>95125</PostalCode>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <ItemSpecifics>
         <NameValueList>
            <Name>Title</Name>
            <Value>Harry Potter and the Philosophers Stone</Value>
         </NameValueList>
         <NameValueList>
            <Name>Publisher</Name>
            <Value>Smashwords</Value>
         </NameValueList>
         <NameValueList>
            <Name>Author</Name>
            <Value>JK Rowling</Value>
         </NameValueList>
         <NameValueList>
            <Name>Language</Name>
            <Value>English</Value>
         </NameValueList>
      </ItemSpecifics>
      <ReturnPolicy>
        <ReturnsAcceptedOption>ReturnsAccepted</ReturnsAcceptedOption>
        <RefundOption>MoneyBack</RefundOption>
        <ReturnsWithinOption>Days_30</ReturnsWithinOption>
        <ShippingCostPaidByOption>Buyer</ShippingCostPaidByOption>
      </ReturnPolicy>
      <ShippingDetails>
        <ShippingType>Flat</ShippingType>
        <ShippingServiceOptions>
          <ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>
          <ShippingService>USPSMedia</ShippingService>
          <ShippingServiceCost>2.50</ShippingServiceCost>
        </ShippingServiceOptions>
      </ShippingDetails>
      <Site>US</Site>
  </Item>
</AddItemRequest>
```

Comment: `print(r.text)` and show output?

Comment: You are a legend:) lol, I'm like a real noob... You can. post the answer and I can upvote it if you like:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be very new to `requests` module. Just read the [docs](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and the hello world example will solve your problem.

We often use `r.text` for text, `r.content` for binary, `r.json` for json. `r.status_code` and `r.reason` for exception debugging.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I should have read more of the docs...